# Spark Function2 dont match params types

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, reduce

When I try to get a action from x rdd:
I try to pass a JavaRDD for each call to process something.

Any hints?

```
JavaRDD<AlertedAffiliations> result  = rddComm.reduce( new Function2<CommercesVars,JavaRDD<Rules>,AlertedAffiliations >(){
public AlertedAffiliations call( CommercesVars commVars, JavaRDD<Rules> x ){
    ....
    some x process
    ....
    return new AlertedAffiliations( commVars.getAffiliation() ,true);
}}
```

I got the next error:

cannot be applied to given types;
  required:

```
org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2<
    com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
    com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
    com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars>
```

found:

```
 <anonymous org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2<
  com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
  org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<com.mx.monic.utils.Rules>,
  com.mx.monic.utils.AlertedAffiliations>>
```

reason:

```
  actual argument <
  anonymous          
  org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2<
  com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
  org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<com.mx.monic.utils.Rules>,
  com.mx.monic.utils.AlertedAffiliations>>
```

cannot be converted to

```
  org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2<
  com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
  com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars,
  com.mx.monic.utils.CommercesVars> 

  by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce` function doesn't work the way you seem to be using it, instead of returning another RDD `reduce` will collapse it down to results on the driver. As such the method signature you've provided doesn't work for reduce.

Comment: Hi, got it, so if i want to process 2 Rdd like this. RddA every element with every element on RddB, using something like crosstab can i make it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm correctly parsing your comment, but it sounds like you want to use `cartesian`.

Comment: Yep, already noticed that, thanks. i have to buy a spark`s book. ;)

Comment: I have a slightly biased view of which one you should buy :p

Answer (score 0):

I try to  operate over each combination of 2 Rdd,
so i though if iterate over each element, like this

```
for( ){
   for(){
      bla bla bla
   }
}

In Rdd that is wrong

Rdd_A.reduce(new Function2<CommercesVars,Rdd_B,AlertedAffiliations>(){
     public AlertedAffiliations call(){
               bla
               bla
               bla
               reurn AlertedAffiliations(......);
     }
});
```

Solution:

```
JavaPairRDD<Rules,CommercesVars> rddPairCartesian = rddRules.cartesian( rddComm );
rddPairCartesian.map( bla,bla bla);
```

So in this form i can operate over each combination.